# Map.setCenter using a variable in Google Earth Image

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

How can I pass a variable to `Map.setCenter`? I'm trying to use GEE to to view a location that comes from a variable. That is, the following works:

```js
var scene = "LC80122482013122LGN01"
var compare = ee.String('LANDSAT_SCENE_ID == "').cat(scene).cat('"')
var im = ee.ImageCollection.load('LANDSAT/LC8_L1T_TOA').filter(ee.Filter.expression(compare))
var IM = ee.Image(im.first());
Map.setCenter(-27.4713134765625, 81.4474921754631, 10)
Map.addLayer(IM);
```

But if I try to center based on variables that come from a string, I get an error message. For example, by adding

```js
var lon = ee.Number.parse(ee.String("-27.4713134765625"));
Map.setCenter(lon, 81.4474921754631, 10)
```

So the full example is:

```js
var scene = "LC80122482013122LGN01"
var compare = ee.String('LANDSAT_SCENE_ID == "').cat(scene).cat('"')
var im = ee.ImageCollection.load('LANDSAT/LC8_L1T_TOA').filter(ee.Filter.expression(compare))
var IM = ee.Image(im.first());
var lon = ee.Number.parse(ee.String("-27.4713134765625"));
Map.setCenter(lon, 81.4474921754631, 10)
Map.addLayer(IM);
```

I get the error message

> Provided center object has invalid values for lat, lon, or zoom.
> Expected numeric values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Map.setCenter` is expecting number-objects on the client side as arguments, and in your example `lon` is actually a number-object on the server side. Thus, an easy way to transform a server side object to a client side one is using `getInfo()`. Here's the only change you need to make to your code. If you want to read more about server vs client side objects I suggest taking a look to the following link: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server

```
Map.setCenter(lon.getInfo(), 81.4474921754631, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Map.setCenter`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ui-map-setcenter) is expecting client-side JavaScript numeric literal arguments. The `lon` variable is a server-side [ee.Number](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-number). When you pass it as an argument to `Map.setCenter`, it is interpreted literally as the serialized expression graph that represents the number.

The `Map` object is a special case of [`ui.Map`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ui-map) and all `ui` components are client-side objects that expect client-side arguments, except when `ee` objects are specifically requested, like the `eeObject` parameter for [`Map.addLayer`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/map-addlayer) or the `image` parameter for [`ui.Thumbnail`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ui-thumbnail).

To transfer a server-side object client-side, use the `evaluate` method ([`ee.Number.evaluate`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-number-evaluate) in this case). The `evaluate` method is preferred over [`getInfo`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-number-getinfo) because it is asynchronous (i.e. it will not block any remaining computations while the object is retrieved – it will not cause your browser to hang).

```js
var serverSideLon = ee.Number.parse(ee.String("-27.4713134765625"));

serverSideLon.evaluate(function(clientSideLon) {
  Map.setCenter(clientSideLon, 81.4474921754631, 10);
});
```

Comment: The fact that the majority of `ui` component arguments need to be client-side JavaScript literals is not well documented/highlighted in the Earth Engine Guide pages. I'll submit a request to add a linkable section that describes it.